# Recognizing images and incorporating into code

Tags: python, image, image-processing

I have a programming project in mind, but have only scratched the surface of my programming experience. I'm just about done with my first Python class, so that's about how much experience I have.
Now my question, is it possible to read and recognize an image (business card/playing card/ image with text) and produce an operation based on the information read? The image would be at a distance, and I would be using a camera or xbox kinect.

Answer (score 0):

yeah it's possible, you can train machine learning models.

Comment: Would it also be possible to program LED sequences to go with the different images?